# Combine Document Class and TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, combine

I'm trying to combine several articles into a single volume using the `combine` document class. Some of the articles use the `TikZ` package, which seems to cause problems during compilation. For example, if my main file is

```
\documentclass{combine}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{papers}
\coltoctitle{Paper 1}
\coltocauthor{A.~Author}
\import{./author1/paper}
\end{papers}
\end{document}
```

and the document `paper.tex` in the directory `author1` has the contents

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{My Paper}
\author{A.~Author}
\date{2013}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
My paper.
\end{document}
```

then compiling the main document fails with the message `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=5000].` But if I remove the `TikZ` package from the main document, then everything works fine. (Of course that's not an option when the included file actually makes use of the package.) Short of manually converting all the `TikZ` pictures to image files, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Try to compile your document with LuaTex, ie `lualatex mydocument.tex`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That seems to be an incompatibility; something around the everyshi package and the hooks which are installed by tikz cause an endless loop.

I am unaware of immediate fixes for the root cause (which would be fine; I suggest you ask the author of the combine package on what is going on), but one way might be to use the external library.

Here, I want to elaborate the use of the external library. It may or may not be an option; but it could be worth a try.

Assume that *all* your included papers which make use of tikz also use the external library which is shipped with tikz. As a consequence, *all* their pictures are also available as separate `.pdf`s. Then (and only then) can you get rid of `\usepackage{tikz}`. Clearly, you want to avoid the necessity to touch every input file! Fortunately, the external lib comes with an option which does not need `tikz` but can read the external `.pdf`s.

To this end, you have to uncomment every `\usepackage{tikz}` and use `\usepackage{tikzexternal}` instead. The file `tikzexternal.sty` is a style file which kind of "supports" the environment `\begin{tikzpicture} ...\end{tikzpicture}` in the sense that it replaces the environment by the associated externalized `.pdf` - without more action from your part.

The only problem is that the papers might contain preamble configurations. These would need to be deactivated. Fortunately, the `tikzexternal` package already deactivates `\tikzset`, `\pgfkeys` and some more. You can deactivate more if you need to (by defining any undefined macros by dummies).

Here is your minimal example:

main document:

```
\documentclass{combine}
\usepackage{tikzexternal}
\begin{document}
\begin{papers}
\coltoctitle{Paper 1}
\coltocauthor{A.~Author}
\import{paper}
\end{papers}
\end{document}
```

file `paper.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{My Paper}
\author{A.~Author}
\date{2013}

\usepackage{tikzexternal}
%\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\tikzset{/some/option/.initial=just to see what happens}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
My paper.

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) grid (10,10);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You see that I modified `paper.tex` such that it actually makes use of tikz.

Naturally, you would need to compile it first with `tikz` and its external library, i.e. you would need to (a) reactivate `\usepackage{tikz}` and `\usetikzlibrary{external}` (b) deactivate `\usepackage{tikzexternal}` and run `pdflatex -shell-escape paper.tex`. Then, switch back to `tikzexternal` (i.e. to the code above) and compile `main.tex` as usual.

If you have papers containing `pgfplots` code, you may need to uncomment `\usepackage{pgfplots}` as well and say

```
\def\pgfplotsset#1{}
```

in order to replace its configuration macro by an empty dummy.

POSSIBLE CAVEATS:

- `tikzexternal.sty` might not reflect recent changes in tikz, i.e. it may be incomplete or buggy.
- if the papers make use of `\label` or `\ref` to reference images inside of `pgfplots` code, I do not really know if `tikzexternal.sty` is able to resolve these special reference. This is a special case.

Comment: I don't seem to have the `external` library in my distribution, nor can I find it in the most recent `pgf` distribution available on CTAN. Where should I be looking?

Comment: It is in http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/tex/latex/pgf/utilities

Comment: it was originally intented for guys who do not even have tikz, so it should be ok if you copy-paste it to your installation (into the current working directory)

Comment: This worked beautifully with the first paper. The second paper is failing to compile when `\tikzexternalize` is present. The log file for the first picture file says `! Package graphics Error: Division by 0.` The strange thing is that, as far as I can tell, I can compile any individual part of the file that doesn't include more than one `tikzpicture` environment. I can get partway through the paper by successively uncommenting the pictures, but this breaks down before I've finished.

Comment: That sounds strange. If I am not mistaken, it is unrelated to `tikzexternal.sty`; it is just the externalization of the images as such. Perhaps the second paper redefines something or has other special settings which hamper the operation. I fear you will need to isolate the problem (as minimal working example) and ask a new question.